# Huawei browser slider horizontal scrolling changes page location

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In Huawei Browser, when I use a slider and try to scroll horizontally on my mobile phone it results in a `window.location` path change, instead of a scroll. If I scroll left it opens the previous page, scrolling right opens the next page.

It works fine if I turn off that “swiping“ feature in the “Huawei Browser“ settings.